# Getting "WARNING: Found unexpected Attribute (name = NestHost)" when running calculations on the gpu using the aparapi api in java

Tags: java, gpu, hardware, aparapi

I am creating a program that needs to run many calculations simultaneously so i looked for a gpu solution to make it run faster. I implemented the code found here: https://github.com/Syncleus/aparapi-examples/tree/master/src/main/java/com/aparapi/examples/add into this function that would add 2 arrays of values on the GPU:

```
    public static double[] addWithGPU(double[] a, double[] b) {
        final double[] sum = new double[a.length];

        Kernel kernel = new Kernel(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int gid = getGlobalId();
                sum[gid] = a[gid] + b[gid];
            }
        };

        kernel.execute(Range.create(a.length));

        kernel.dispose();
        return sum;
    }
```

I used this code in my main class:

```
    public Main() {
        GPU.addWithGPU(new double[] {1, 2, 3}, new double[] {3, 2, 1});
        thread = new Thread(() -> {
            // Code here
        });
        thread.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
```

I also tried this:

```
    final double[] a1 = {1, 2, 3};
    final double[] a2 = {3, 2, 1};

    public Main() {
        GPU.addWithGPU(a1, a2);
        thread = new Thread(() -> {
            // Code here
        });
        thread.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
```

I also tried to make the "addWithGPU" function non static however i still got the error of:

> com.aparapi.internal.model.ClassModel$AttributePool 
> WARNING: Found unexpected Attribute (name = NestHost)

Somtimes the code just continues running after the error however sometimes the program just hangs, and it is inconsistent, I belive it may be based on if any other programs are using my GPU at the time however I am not sure.

My PC specs are:
GPU: Nvidia RTX 3060, CPU: Intel Core i9 12900KF, Motherboard: ASUS PRIME Z690-P d4 wifi and the software I am using is IntelliJ IDEA CE

I also would prefer and answer using the aparapi api since I am not great at low level programming, but i will be open so swiching api's if the aparapi api is simply out of date or has a complicated solution where it would just be simpler to swap api's.